# how to create state array react hooks on declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

How do I create a state array with react hooks? I am passing a Type 
I used this method but it's showing me lint error.
I also want to know it's the correct method

```
const [myList, setList] = React.useState<IList[]>([
  {
    ID: 1,
    Lname: "R1",
    LType: 1
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    Lname: "R4",
    LType: 5
  }
]);
```

And my type looks like

```
interface IList {
  ID: number;
  Lname: string;
  LType: number;
}
```

Comment: Please add the lint error text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell it it's an *array* of objects. [Here's a codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-galois-j8lvw) of this typing working now.

```
const [myList, setList] = React.useState<IList[]>([
        {
            ID: 1,
            Lname: "R1",
            LType: 1
        }, {
            ID: 2,
            Lname: "R4",
            LType: 5
        }])
```

Comment: I passed like that only.
i forget to mention. still its showing lint

Comment: Argument of type '({ ID: number; Lname: string; LType: number; } | { ID: number; Lname: string; LType: number; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IList | (() => IList)'.

Comment: At this point, I suspect the issue is actually where you're using `setList` somewhere else in the app.

Comment: Here's an example of that typing working just fine https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-galois-j8lvw

Comment: I tried by changing the name. But still its showing the same.
And @Nick you great, with give an example. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing in the wrong type for state. Instead of `IList`, it looks like it should be `IList[]`

If you're still seeing errors, it might be useful to share them.